# Comparing VisualVM and Eclipse TPTP

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling, monitoring, visualvm

What is the difference between VisualVM and Eclipse TPTP?

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that TPTP is being "archived."

From http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm:

> After many successful releases of
>   TPTP, the project has evolved and
>   matured.  However, participation in
>   the project has dwindled over time. 
>   TPTP has been in maintenance mode
>   since TPTP 4.5.0 and at this point of
>   the project cycle, the PMC has decided
>   that TPTP 4.7 will be the last major
>   release of TPTP (part of the  Eclipse
>   Helio release).

Comment: Actually, the one in Netbeans was the source of VisualVM which has evolved so that it can be used independently from Netbeans. As of now, it's exactly the same profiler.

Comment: @BalusC - I was curious if they were related. Thanks! I removed that non-useful part of the post.